# How to fix error in magento2.2.6?

Tags: magento2.2.6

When we click on stores setting configuration then coming this error?

> Notice: Undefined index: id in
>   /home/213836.cloudwaysapps.com/ehanwfcbkq/public_html/app/code/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php
>   on line 63

Error log record number: 200541276044

Comment: Did you install any extension? Or working with default magento 2.2.6?

Comment: yes i installed these extensions http://prntscr.com/lk6htj.

Comment: Do you have Mageplaza Core module installed and active?

Comment: Try to add tab id to system.xml inside adminhtml folder of that module

Comment: not active http://prntscr.com/lk6kop please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the screenshot http://prntscr.com/lk6kop, it seems that Mageplaza_Core module is not enabled, which needs to be enabled since the node:

```
<tab id="mageplaza" translate="label" sortOrder="401" class="mageplaza-extensions">
    <label>Mageplaza Extensions</label>
</tab>
```

is being referenced from the system.xml file of Mageplaza_Productslider module while you try to open the settings.

To fix this, connect to the server's SSH and change directory to the document root of your Magento.

Then run the following command:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Mageplaza_Core
```

or

```
php bin/magento mo:en Mageplaza_Core
```

Please let me know if the problem gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the Mageplaza Core module because the tab code is in its system.xml.

Or you may also add tab in slider module system.xml:

```
<tab id="Mageplaza" translate="label" sortOrder="200">
    <label>Mageplaza</label>
</tab>
```

Answer (score 0):

This Error page shows because the Tab which you have defined in system.xml of your module is not available in any system.xml of your project so modify your system.xml as below

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
       <system>        
          <tab id="api" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
              <label>General Configuration</label>
          </tab>
          <section id="general_section" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
             <label>General Section</label>
             <tab>api</tab>
             <resource>Module_General::configuration</resource>      
             <group id="heard_about" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="10" translate="label">
                 <label>General view</label>
                 <field id="heard_about" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                 <label>General Options</label>
                 ...
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>              
</system>
```